# QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running: How to proper use QThreads with QTimers?

Tags: python, timer, qthread, pyside6

I'm having a bit of a hassle of understanding what is happening in following test code.

I've created a timer which will go into a thread. This thread can be stopped within the object but when deployed in a main QT application, the thread somehow get's garbage collected when the main application ends.

**Q:** How can I proper stop the QThread before the main application ends.(Or implement the thread in a better way? )

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, QThread
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QHBoxLayout

class Counter(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.cnt = 0

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.__update_by_timer)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setText(str(self.cnt))

        self._layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self._layout.addWidget(self.label,  Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)

        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.timer.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start(QThread.Priority.LowestPriority)


    def __del__(self):
        self.thread.exit()

    def __update_by_timer(self):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.label.setText(str(self.cnt))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cnt = Counter()
    cnt.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Main application screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Please remember that you shall only ask *one* question per post. By the way, can you try to clarify what you mean with your second question?

Comment: I've got in my current application a Paint event (instead of this counter )going but this can't be moved to a thread I realized after some reading. I'll edit the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to my problem,

The issue: If you click the app window away, there will be no call to the destructor of the "Counter" object so the timer within the thread lives somewhat apart from the GUI app.

To overcome this I've included a destructor which stops the timer and closes the thread. This must be called by the "closeEvent" method which must be derived from the QWidget class.

```
def __del__(self):
    self.timer.stop()
    self.thread.quit()

def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent) -> None:
    ''' Derived method from QWidget '''
    self.__del__()
    super().closeEvent(event)
```

One extra caveat in the original code is the timer itself. This must be take the "Counter" class of a parent before this can be stopped in the destructor.

```
    self.timer = QTimer(self)
```

Comment: Do *not* call `__del__`, nor rely on it being actually called if you need to do important stuff in there. The proper solution is indeed to create the timer with a parent, and call `thread.quit()` in the `closeEvent()` or, better, connect to the [`aboutToQuit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal of the application.

Comment: Why is this __del__ call not reliable? If I move it all to closeEvent then I omit every destructor actions, don't I?

Comment: `__del__` does *not* call any destructor, it's a "finalizer" that *may* be called when the last reference to the object is being deleted. This may or may *not* happen under certain circumstances (which can happen *often* in Qt, as the python reference may be deleted, but the object can still exist and work on the C++ side), and, while in your case it should almost certainly work, it's still good practice to not rely on it for important tasks. Most importantly, the order of deletion is delicate and not always consistent with PyQt and PySide. See [this post](//stackoverflow.com/q/1481488).

Comment: @musicamante I find this uncertainty of execution not really in favor of PyQT which feels then buggy and unreliable.  I'll see how I'll cope with this new info.  Thank You ;-)

Comment: It's not a "bug". You have to remember that PyQt (as PySide) is a binding around a C++ library. There are various reasons for which an object could keep a reference, and this actually happens even in Python under certain conditions, and that's why you *cannot* rely on `__del__` being called even without considering the usage of external libraries. The C++ wrapping is just a further layer of complexity, as you have to consider the python gc which could never, *ever* know every existing relationship on the C++ side. It's not a bug, it's implicit in working with two different memory managements.